# How do I access Navigation Controller declared in AppDelegate from view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xamarin

Basically, I have created an underlying `UINavigationController`  that my view is sitting in. I can create elements in it from the `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad` method, but I can't access the `UINavigationController` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `self.navigationController`

Answer (score 1):

In ViewDidLoad you can use self.navigationController to access navigation controller.